# ORA-20762: Error-01002: fetch out of sequence encountered on line procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, scheduler, select-for-update

I have a scheduler job(procedure), this scheduler job should run flawless. Its working as per the logic.  This procedure doesn't have any input parameter. It has three to four cursor fetching the data and update the in same table condition wise the cursors work. The problem is... let me tell a scenario. Let say a table called 'sample' inside the procedure I just using a cursor fetch the record and updating the value in the 'sample' table, I commit next to end loop of the cursor. I'm using plsql developer IDE. I'm trying to access the data from table 'sample' as same record fetched in the cursor by putting
`select val1,val2 from sample where val3='A' for update;` in plsql developer ide without click commit button at the same time the job i.e. procedure runs. Its throwing error that `ORA-20762: Error-01002: fetch out of sequence encountered on line procedure`  the error pointing `fetch cursor into ..`. I have used the `'FOR UPDATE NOWAIT'` in cursor sql.

```
         CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE scheduler_job_test
            
             AS
                VARIABLE declarations;
                .        . . . . cur_ex_hnd SYS_REFCURSOR;
                TYPE rec_typ IS RECORD(
                    sch_cde         temp_table1.sch_cde%TYPE,
                    j_tx_n          temp_table1.jh1_pan_no%TYPE,
                    j2_tx_n         temp_table1.jh2_pan_no%TYPE,
                    g_tax_no        temp_table1.guardian_panno%TYPE,
                    tax_no          temp_table1.tax_no%TYPE,
                    cons_code       temp_table1.brok_dlr_code%TYPE,
                    tax_status_code temp_table1.tax_status_code%TYPE,
                    inv_name        temp_table1.inv_name%TYPE,
                    inv_mid_name    temp_table1.inv_mid_name%TYPE,
                    inv_lst_name    temp_table1.inv_lst_name%TYPE);
                ci_tt_dts      rec_typ;
                ls_sql         CLOB;
                ls_sql_1       VARCHAR2(4000);
                ls_sql_2       VARCHAR2(4000);
                ls_sql_3       CLOB;
                ls_sql_4       CLOB;
                dt_ref_cur     SYS_REFCURSOR;
                tt_ref_cur     SYS_REFCURSOR;
                dt_trxn_avl    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
                TYPE ttcurtyp IS REF CURSOR;
                v_tt_cursor    ttcurtyp;
                lld_entry_date temp_table1.entry_date%TYPE;
            
            BEGIN
            
                SELECT trunc(SYSDATE)
                  INTO ld_entry_date
                  FROM dual;
                SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) - 1
                  INTO ld_previous_date
                  FROM dual;
            
                ld_entry_date    := to_char(to_date(ld_entry_date), 'dd-Mon-YYYY');
                ld_previous_date := to_char(to_date(ld_previous_date), 'dd-Mon-YYYY');
            
                ls_sql := 'SELECT
                   sch_cde,
                   j_tx_n,
                   j2_tx_n,
                   g_tax_no,
                   tax_no,
                   cons_code,
                   tax_status_code,
                   inv_name,
                   inv_mid_name,
                   inv_lst_name
                   --fl_no,
              FROM (SELECT
               dt.sch_cde,
               nvl(j1.tax_no,j1.pan_exem_ref_no) j_tx_n,
               nvl(j2.tax_no,j2.pan_exem_ref_no) j2_tx_n,
              .
              .
              .
              
               ,im.inv_lst_name 
                FROM dt_trd dt,
               inv_mst im,
               jnt_hlds j1,
               jnt_hlds j2,
               trxn_charges_setup tc,
                TAX_STATUS t,
                sch_setp ss
               WHERE dt.fl_no = im.fl_no AND
               dt.fl_no = j1.fl_no(+) AND
               j1.joint_no(+) = 1 AND
              .
              .
              .
              .';
            
                ls_sql_1 := 'SELECT tt.sch_cde sch_cde,
               nvl(nvl(tt.jh1_pan_no,tt.jh1_pan_exem_ref_no), nvl(j1.tax_no,j1.pan_exem_ref_no)) j_tx_n,
              .
              .
              .
              
                FROM temp_table1 tt,
               inv_mst im,
               jnt_hlds j1,
               jnt_hlds j2,
               trxn_charges_setup tc,
               tax_status t,
               sch_setp ss
               WHERE tt.fl_no = im.fl_no(+) AND
               tt.fl_no = j1.fl_no(+) AND
               j1.joint_no(+) = 1 AND
               tt.fl_no = j2.fl_no(+) AND
               j2.joint_no(+) = 2 AND
               .
               .
               .
               .
                 GROUP BY sch_cde,
                  j_tx_n,
                  j2_tx_n,
                  g_tax_no,
                  tax_no,
                  cons_code,
                  tax_status_code,
                  inv_name,
                  inv_mid_name,
                  inv_lst_name 
            
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';
            
                ls_sql_2 := 'SELECT dt.sch_cde,
                 nvl(j1.tax_no,j1.pan_exem_ref_no)               j_tx_n,
                .
                .
                .
                
                 im.inv_lst_name
                FROM dt_trd         dt,
                 inv_mst    im,
                 jnt_hlds      j1,
                 jnt_hlds      j2,
                 trxn_charges_setup tc,
                 TAX_STATUS         t
               WHERE dt.fl_no = im.fl_no
                .
                .
                .
                .
                
                 AND tc.trxn_db_cr = ''P''
                 AND tc.trxn_type_flag IN (''AP'', ''FP'')
                .
                .
                .
                AND
                 NOT EXISTS
                   (SELECT 1
              FROM temp_table1 tt
                   WHERE dt.fl_no = tt.fl_no AND
                   dt.trxn_no = tt.original_trxn_no AND
                   nvl(dt.trxn_mode, ''N'') <> ''R'') AND
             .
             .
             .
             ';
                ls_sql_3 := '
               SELECT sch_cde,
               j_tx_n,
               j2_tx_n,
               g_tax_no,
               tax_no,
               cons_code,
               tax_status_code,
                NULL inv_name,
                NULL inv_mid_name,
                NULL inv_lst_name
                FROM (
                SELECT tt.sch_cde sch_cde,
               nvl(nvl(tt.jh1_pan_no,tt.jh1_pan_exem_ref_no), nvl(j1.tax_no,j1.pan_exem_ref_no)) j_tx_n,
              .
              .
              .
                 nvl(tt.inv_lst_name, im.inv_lst_name)
                FROM temp_table1 tt,
                 inv_mst           im,
                 jnt_hlds             j1,
                 jnt_hlds             j2,
                 trxn_charges_setup        tc,
                 tax_status                t,
                 sch_setp ss
               WHERE tt.fl_no = im.fl_no(+)
                .
                .
                .
                 AND nvl(tt.tax_status_code, im.tax_status_code) = t.tax_status_code
                 and upper(nvl(tt.sub_trxn_type,''N'')) IN (''NORMAL'', ''N'')
                 AND tt.trxn_type LIKE ''P%''
                 .
                  . 
            .
            .
            .
            .
            
               GROUP BY sch_cde,
                    j_tx_n,
                    j2_tx_n,
                    g_tax_no,
                    tax_no,
                    cons_code, 
                    tax_status_code
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';
            
                BEGIN
                    ls_sql_4 := ls_sql || ' UNION ALL ' || ls_sql_1 || ' UNION ALL ' ||
                            ls_sql_2 || ' UNION ALL ' || ls_sql_3;
                    OPEN cur_ex_hnd FOR ls_sql_4;
                    LOOP
                        FETCH cur_ex_hnd
                            INTO ci_tt_dts;
                        EXIT WHEN cur_ex_hnd%NOTFOUND;
                        ls_sql      := NULL;
                        dt_trxn_avl := FALSE;
                        ls_sql      := 'SELECT
                             dt.sch_cde,
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            
                             im.guardian_panno g_tax_no,
                             im.tax_no         tax_no,
                             nvl(itn_plf_last_broker_conscode(dt.brok_dlr_code), ''ARN-DIRECT'') cons_code,
                            dt.entry_date,
                             im.tax_status_code tax_status_code
                               ,im.inv_name
                               ,im.inv_mid_name
                               ,im.inv_lst_name
                            FROM dt_trd         dt,
                             inv_mst    im,
                             jnt_hlds      j1,
                             jnt_hlds      j2,
                             trxn_charges_setup tc
                           WHERE dt.fl_no = im.fl_no AND
                             dt.fl_no = j1.fl_no(+) AND
                             j1.joint_no(+) = 1 AND
                             dt.fl_no = j2.fl_no(+) AND
                             j2.joint_no(+) = 2 AND
            .
            .
            .
            ';
                    
                        IF ld_entry_date IS NOT NULL THEN
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  ' AND trunc(dt.entry_date) BETWEEN trunc(tc.from_date) AND trunc(tc.to_date) ';
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  ' AND dt.trxn_type_flag NOT LIKE ''NFO%'' AND dt.entry_date between to_date(:bv_p_as_date || ''15:00:00'',''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') and to_date(:bv_entry_date || ''14:59:59'',''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'')';
                        ELSE
                            ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND 1 = :bv_entry_date ';
                            ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND 1 = :bv_p_as_date ';
                        END IF;
                    
                        IF ci_tt_dts.tax_no IS NOT NULL THEN
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  ' AND (im.tax_no = :bv_tax_no or im.pan_exem_ref_no = :bv_tax_no)  ';
                        ELSE
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  'and (1 =:bv_tax_no or 1 =:bv_tax_no) ';
                        END IF;
                    
                        IF ci_tt_dts.j_tx_n IS NOT NULL THEN
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  ' AND (j1.tax_no = :bv_j1_tax_no or j1.pan_exem_ref_no = :bv_j1_tax_no) ';
                        ELSE
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  'AND (1 = :bv_j1_tax_no or 1 = :bv_j1_tax_no) ';
                        END IF;
                    
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                        IF ci_tt_dts.inv_lst_name IS NOT NULL THEN
                            ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                  ' AND upper(im.inv_lst_name) = upper(:bv_investor_last_name) ';
                        ELSE
                            ls_sql := ls_sql || 'AND 1 = :bv_investor_last_name ';
                        END IF;
                        OPEN dt_ref_cur FOR to_char(ls_sql)
                            USING ci_tt_dts.sch_cde, ci_tt_dts.cons_code, ci_tt_dts.tax_status_code, ld_previous_date, ld_entry_date, nvl(ci_tt_dts.tax_no,
                                                                                      '1'), nvl(ci_tt_dts.tax_no,
                                                                                        '1'), nvl(ci_tt_dts.j_tx_n,
                                                                                            .
                                                                                            .
                                                                                            .
                                                                                            .
                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                      '1');
                    
                        ll_dt_rowcount := 0;
                        LOOP
                            FETCH dt_ref_cur
                                INTO ls_dt_scheme_code,
                                     ls_dt_user_code,
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
                                     ;
                            EXIT WHEN dt_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;
                        
                            ll_dt_rowcount := dt_ref_cur%ROWCOUNT;
                        
                            IF ll_dt_rowcount = 1 THEN
                                ls_temp_user_code   := ls_dt_user_code;
                                ls_temp_user_trxnno := ls_dt_user_trxnno;
                                dt_trxn_avl         := TRUE;
                                EXIT;
                            END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                        IF dt_trxn_avl = TRUE THEN
                            ls_sql := NULL;
                            ls_sql := 'SELECT tt.fl_no fl_no,
                               tt.user_code,
                               tt.user_trxnno,
                              .
                              .
                              .
                              
                              ,nvl(tt.inv_mid_name,im.inv_mid_name) 
                              ,nvl(tt.inv_lst_name,im.inv_lst_name) 
                          FROM temp_table1 tt,
                               inv_mst           im,
                               jnt_hlds             j1,
                               jnt_hlds             j2,
                               trxn_charges_setup        tc,
                               sch_setp ss 
                         WHERE tt.fl_no = im.fl_no(+) AND
                               tt.fl_no = j1.fl_no(+) AND
                               j1.joint_no(+) = 1 AND
                               tt.fl_no = j2.fl_no(+) AND
                               j2.joint_no(+) = 2 AND
            .
            .
            .
            .
            ';
                        
                            IF ld_entry_date IS NOT NULL THEN
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND
                                  ((tt.entry_date BETWEEN
                                  to_date(:bv_p_as_date || '' 15 :00 :00 '',
                                        '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss '') AND
                                  to_date(:bv_entry_date || '' 14 :59 :59 '',
                                        '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss ''))
                                   ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' OR
                                   ((tt.trade_date < trunc(tt.entry_date) AND
                                   tt.trade_date = :bv_entry_date) AND
                                   upper(tt.source_program) = '' appl
                                    '' AND upper(tt.user_code) <> '' mobile ''))
                                  ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND
                                  ((ss.open_date < :bv_entry_date) AND
                                  (nvl(ss.allotment_date, ss.open_date) <
                                  :bv_entry_date)) ';
                            ELSE
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND
                                  1 = :bv_entry_date ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND
                                  1 = :bv_p_as_date
                                  ';
                            END IF;
                        
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            ';
                            END IF;
                            ls_sql := ls_sql || ' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT ';
                            OPEN tt_ref_cur FOR to_char(ls_sql)
                                USING ls_dt_scheme_code, ls_dt_tax_status_code, ls_dt_brok_dlr_code, ld_previous_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, nvl(ls_dt_tax_no,
                                                                                                               ' 1 '), nvl(ls_dt_tax_no,
                                                                                                                   ' 1 '), nvl(ls_dt_guardian_panno,.
                                                                                                                   .
                                                                                                                   .
                                                                                                                   .
                                                                                                                   .
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                   ' 1 '), nvl(ls_dt_investor_last_name,
                                                                                                                                                                           ' 1 ');
                        
                            LOOP
                            
                                FETCH tt_ref_cur
                                    INTO ls_folio_no,
                                         ls_user_code,
                                         ls_user_trxnno,
                                         ls_scheme_code,
                                         .
                                         .
                                         .
                                         .
                                EXIT WHEN tt_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;
                            
                                ll_tt_rowcount := tt_ref_cur%ROWCOUNT;
                                as_strflag     := ' entry_date ';
                                UPDATE temp_table1 tt
                                   SET tc_option = ' na ',
                                       remarks   = substr(REPLACE(remarks,
                                                  ' < # ' ||
                                                  ls_temp_user_code ||
                                                  ' $ ' ||
                                                  to_char(ls_temp_user_trxnno) ||
                                                  ' # > ',
                                                  NULL) || ' < # ' ||
                                              ls_temp_user_code ||
                                              ' $ ' ||
                                              to_char(ls_temp_user_trxnno) ||
                                              ' # > ' ||
                                              ' tc OPTION updated ' ||
                                              ' _ ' || as_strflag ||
                                              ' - ' || ld_entry_date ||
                                              ' AND located ON ' ||
                                              to_char(SYSDATE,
                                                  ' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss ') ||
                                              ' > ',
                                              1,
                                              1000)
                                 WHERE tt.user_code = ls_user_code AND
                                       tt.user_trxnno = ls_user_trxnno AND
                                       tt.sch_cde = ls_scheme_code AND
                                       tt.trxn_type = ls_trxn_type;
                            
                                IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
                                    as_result := ' RECORD NOT available IN cdt ';
                                ELSE
                                    as_result := ' updated ';
                                END IF;
                                COMMIT;
                            
                            END LOOP;
                            CLOSE tt_ref_cur;
                        ELSE
                            ls_sql := NULL;
                            ls_sql := ' SELECT tt.fl_no fl_no, tt.user_code, tt.user_trxnno, tt.sch_cde sch_cde, tt.trxn_type, tt.amount, nvl(tt.jh1_pan_no, j1.tax_no) j_tx_n, nvl(tt.jh2_pan_no, j2.tax_no) j2_tx_n, nvl(tt.guardian_panno, im.guardian_panno) g_tax_no, nvl(tt.tax_no, im.tax_no) tax_no,
            
                             nvl(tt.cons_code, nvl(itn_plf_last_broker_conscode(tt.brok_dlr_code), '' arn - direct '')) cons_code, tt.entry_date, nvl(tt.tax_status_code, im.tax_status_code) tax_status_code, nvl(tt.inv_name, im.inv_name)
                             , nvl(tt.inv_mid_name, im.inv_mid_name)
                             , nvl(tt.inv_lst_name, im.inv_lst_name)
                             FROM temp_table1 tt, inv_mst im, jnt_hlds j1, jnt_hlds j2, trxn_charges_setup tc, sch_setp ss WHERE tt.fl_no = im.fl_no(+) AND .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             ';
                        
                            IF ld_entry_date IS NOT NULL THEN
                                ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                      ' AND ((tt.entry_date BETWEEN to_date(:bv_p_as_date || '' 15 :00 :00 '', '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss '') AND to_date(:bv_entry_date || '' 14 :59 :59 '', '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss '')) ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                      ' OR ((tt.trade_date < trunc(tt.entry_date) AND tt.trade_date = :bv_as_date) AND upper(tt.source_program) = '' appl '' AND upper(tt.user_code) <> '' mobile '')) ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                      ' AND ((ss.open_date < :bv_entry_date) AND (nvl(ss.allotment_date, ss.open_date) < :bv_entry_date)) ';
                            ELSE
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND 1 = :bv_entry_date ';
                                ls_sql := ls_sql || ' AND 1 = :bv_p_as_date ';
                            END IF;
                        
                            IF ci_tt_dts.tax_no IS NOT NULL THEN
                                ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                      ' AND (nvl(tt.tax_no, im.tax_no) = :bv_tax_no OR nvl(tt.pan_exem_ref_no, im.pan_exem_ref_no) = :bv_tax_no) ';
                            ELSE
                                ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                                      ' AND (1 = :bv_tax_no OR 1 = :bv_tax_no) ';
                            END IF;
                            . . .
                            
                            ls_sql := ls_sql || ' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT ';
                            OPEN tt_ref_cur FOR to_char(ls_sql)
                                USING ci_tt_dts.sch_cde, ci_tt_dts.tax_status_code, ci_tt_dts.cons_code, ld_previous_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, .
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                nvl(ci_tt_dts.inv_lst_name,
                                                                                                                                                                           ' 1 ');
                        
                            ll_tt_rowcount := 0;
                            LOOP
                                FETCH tt_ref_cur
                                    INTO 
                                    ls_folio_no,ls_user_code,.
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                    ;
                                EXIT WHEN tt_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;
                                ll_tt_rowcount := tt_ref_cur%ROWCOUNT;
                                IF nvl(ll_tt_rowcount, 0) = 1 THEN
                                    ls_dt_user_code   := ls_user_code;
                                    ls_dt_user_trxnno := ls_user_trxnno;
                                ELSE
                                    UPDATE temp_table1 tt
                                       SET tc_option = ' na ',
                                           remarks   = substr(REPLACE(remarks,
                                                      ' < # ' ||
                                                      ls_dt_user_code ||
                                                      ' $ ' ||
                                                      to_char(ls_dt_user_trxnno) ||
                                                      ' # > ',
                                                      NULL) ||
                                                  ' < # ' ||
                                                  ls_dt_user_code ||
                                                  ' $ ' ||
                                                  to_char(ls_dt_user_trxnno) ||
                                                  ' # > ' ||
                                                  ' tc OPTION updated ' ||
                                                  ' _ ' ||
                                                  as_strflag ||
                                                  ' - ' ||
                                                  ld_entry_date ||
                                                  ' AND located ON ' ||
                                                  to_char(SYSDATE,
                                                      ' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss ') ||
                                                  ' > ',
                                                  1,
                                                  1000)
                                     WHERE tt.user_code = ls_user_code AND
                                           tt.user_trxnno = ls_user_trxnno AND
                                           tt.sch_cde = ls_scheme_code AND
                                           tt.trxn_type = ls_trxn_type;
                                    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
                                        as_result := ' RECORD NOT available IN cdt ';
                                    ELSE
                                        as_result := ' updated ';
                                    END IF;
                                
                                    COMMIT;
                                END IF;
                            END LOOP;
                            CLOSE tt_ref_cur;
                        END IF;
                    END LOOP;
                
                    CLOSE cur_ex_hnd;
                
                    ls_sql := '';
                    ls_sql := ls_sql ||
                          ' SELECT tt.user_code, tt.user_trxnno, tt.sch_cde, tt.trxn_type, tt.multi_invest_tc_check FROM temp_table1 tt, sch_setp ss WHERE tt.sch_cde = ss.sch_cde AND tt.trxn_type LIKE '' p% '' AND nvl(tt.multi_invest_tc_check, '' N'') <> '' y '' AND ((tt.entry_date BETWEEN to_date(:bv_p_as_date || '' 15 :00 :00 '', '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss '') AND to_date(:bv_entry_date || '' 14 :59 :59 '', '' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss '')) OR ((tt.trade_date < trunc(tt.entry_date) AND tt.trade_date = :bv_entry_date) AND upper(tt.source_program) = '' appl '' AND upper(tt.user_code) <> '' mobile '')) AND ((ss.open_date < :bv_entry_date) AND (nvl(ss.allotment_date, ss.open_date) < :bv_entry_date)) ';
                    ls_sql := ls_sql || ' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT ';
                    OPEN v_tt_cursor FOR ls_sql
                        USING ld_previous_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date, ld_entry_date;
                    LOOP
                        FETCH v_tt_cursor
                            INTO ls_user_code,
                                 ls_user_trxnno,
                                 ls_scheme_code,
                                 ls_trxn_type,
                                 ls_multi_invest_tc_check;
                        EXIT WHEN v_tt_cursor%NOTFOUND;
                        as_strflag := ' entry_date ';
                        IF nvl(TRIM(ls_multi_invest_tc_check), ' N') <> ' y ' THEN
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE temp_table1 tt
                                   SET tt.multi_invest_tc_check = ' y ',
                                       tt.remarks               = substr(remarks ||
                                                     ' < multi inv tc CHECK updated ' ||
                                                     ' _ ' ||
                                                     as_strflag ||
                                                     ' - ' ||
                                                     ld_entry_date ||
                                                     ' AND located ON ' ||
                                                     to_char(SYSDATE,
                                                         ' dd - mon - yyyy hh24 :mi :ss ') ||
                                                     ' > ',
                                                     1,
                                                     1000)
                                 WHERE tt.user_code = ls_user_code AND
                                       tt.user_trxnno = ls_user_trxnno AND
                                       tt.sch_cde = ls_scheme_code AND
                                       tt.trxn_type = ls_trxn_type;
                                COMMIT;
                                as_result    := ' updated ';
                                li_row_count := li_row_count + 1;
                            EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                    raise_application_error(-20760,
                                                error_trace);
                            END;
                        
                        END IF;
                        BEGIN
                            ld_end_time := SYSDATE;
                            SELECT tt.tc_option,
                                   tt.multi_invest_tc_check
                              INTO ls_tc_option,
                                   ls_multiinvest_check
                              FROM temp_table1 tt
                             WHERE tt.user_code = ls_user_code AND
                                   tt.user_trxnno = ls_user_trxnno;
                            DELETE FROM report_log c
                             WHERE c.table_name = ' schedule_check ' AND
                                   trunc(c.start_time) =
                                   trunc(add_months(SYSDATE, -2));
                            SELECT seq_report_log.nextval
                              INTO ls_sno
                              FROM dual;
                            INSERT INTO report_log
                                (table_name,
                                 report_desc,
                                 start_time,
                                 end_time,
                                 serial_no,
                                 created_date,
                                 selection,
                                 elapsed_time)
                            VALUES
                                (' schedule_check ',
                                 as_result || ' $ ' || ls_user_code || ' $ ' ||
                                 ls_user_trxnno || ' $ ' || ls_scheme_code ||
                                 ' $ ' || ls_tc_option || ' $ ' ||
                                 ls_multiinvest_check,
                                 ld_start_time,
                                 ld_end_time,
                                 ls_sno,
                                 trunc(SYSDATE),
                                 substr(' updated COUNT - ' || li_row_count,
                                    1,
                                    4000),
                                 plf_time_between(ld_start_time,
                                          ld_end_time,
                                          ' m '));
                            COMMIT;
                        EXCEPTION
                            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                raise_application_error(-20761, error_trace);
                        END;
                    
                    END LOOP;
                    CLOSE v_tt_cursor;
                END;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    raise_application_error(-20762, error_trace);
            END;
```

Comment: Please post your code, how can we help you without that ?

Comment: "I commit next to end loop" sounds dodgy, but without your code - or preferably a cut-down version that demonstrates the same problem (see [mcve]), it's impossible to tell what you're really doing.

Comment: Please, we need to see the code. Without it , it is impossible to provide any solution

Comment: The error you are getting indicates you are fetching from a closed cursor either via "close cursor" or never it was never opened. But without the code there is NOT to be said.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#GUID-6A1C2FD9-9476-4F8D-A2E4-2C967D7F8C08):

> When SELECT FOR UPDATE is associated with an explicit cursor, the cursor is called a FOR UPDATE cursor...

and

> The rows of the result set are locked when you open a FOR UPDATE cursor, not as they are fetched. The rows are unlocked when you commit or roll back the transaction. After the rows are unlocked, you cannot fetch from the FOR UPDATE cursor, as Example 6-41 shows (the result is the same if you substitute ROLLBACK for COMMIT).

and example 6-41 shows the same thing that you are doing here:

```
...
ls_sql := ls_sql || ' FOR UPDATE NOWAIT ';
OPEN tt_ref_cur FOR to_char(ls_sql) ...
LOOP

    FETCH tt_ref_cur
        INTO ls_folio_no,
        ...
    EXIT WHEN tt_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;

    ...
    UPDATE temp_table1 tt
       SET tc_option = ' na ',
           ...
     WHERE tt.user_code = ls_user_code AND
           tt.user_trxnno = ls_user_trxnno AND
           tt.sch_cde = ls_scheme_code AND
           tt.trxn_type = ls_trxn_type;

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
        as_result := ' RECORD NOT available IN cdt ';
    ELSE
        as_result := ' updated ';
    END IF;
    COMMIT;

END LOOP;
CLOSE tt_ref_cur;
```

Or in a simplified version against the standard HR schema:

```
declare
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
  l_employee employees%rowtype;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from employees for update';
  loop
    fetch l_cur into l_employee;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_employee.employee_id);
    commit;
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
end;
/

100

Error report -
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Without the commit this outputs all 107 employee IDs. With the commit it outputs the first one, but the commit then unlocks the rows, and the next time around the loop the fetch errors with the same ORA-01002 that you are seeing.

If you take the commit out of the loop and do that once at the end of the procedure then the problem will go away, as here:

```
declare
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
  l_employee employees%rowtype;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from employees for update';
  loop
    fetch l_cur into l_employee;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_employee.employee_id);
    --commit;
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
end;
/

100
101
102
103
104
...
205
206


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You shouldn't generally commit in a loop anyway, even without the `for update` clause, as it can [cause errors](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:546822742166), leave the data in an inconsistent or confusing state and make restarting the process harder. That might not be an issue here, but it's still not a good idea, or necessary. There is a myth that committing frequently speeds up large operations, but it actually slows them down; and you don't need to commit for the rest of the code in the procedure to see the updated rows.

Comment: thanks for the response sir. You said don't use commit inside the loop. Will it slow down the operations. For example about more than 30k or 50k records to update means cursor fetch all the records and stored those in memory and fetch one by one and update all 30k or 50k records and then finally committing. Is it ok? Will it right way to update all the records and finally commit it? if its about 50 or 100 records means ok. i worrying about lot of records thats why....

Comment: @Prog_2918 - yes, it will slow it down, as I said. As long as you have enough undo/rollback for the updates to be held, and 30-50k is nothing really. It's better to update them all at once and then commit once. It won't hold all those rows in memory, it fetches in batches. It would be even better to do a single SQL update statement, instead of doing row-by-row updates in PL/SQL if that's possible.